# SQL-I want to reduce the execution time

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( max(login_time),'%Y-%m-%d') from 
aaa AS b,user AS a where b.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY b.user_id ORDER BY b.user_id
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is it about improving your query?

Comment: You could delete some data from your database or use a faster computer.

Comment: any alternative query for the above

Comment: It seems that you do not need table `a` at all.

Comment: what is the relationship between `aaa` and `user`?

Comment: Which table is `login_time` from? That's the only table you need, you don't need a join.

Comment: i had matched the two tables logged in id and retrieving the lastlogin for each user,so table a is needed

Comment: Never mind, the join is probably right if he only wants results for users that are in both tables.

Comment: if you include only the date in the result set, all you get is a list of dates.

Comment: table user contains all user id and other details,table aaa contains who and all logged into the application

Comment: ya i will get only date...@Jodrell

Comment: Do you have an index on the user_id column?

Comment: Add a primary key or an index on the user_id column. Search for CREATE INDEX or ADD PRIMARY KEY. It is essential.

Comment: Consider providing a little more context including, perhaps, an sqlfiddle, and most importantly, the explain plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly this is a proper statement:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(login_time),'%Y-%m-%d')
    FROM user AS u
    INNER JOIN aaa AS a
       ON u.user_id = a.user_id
    GROUP BY a.user_id
    ORDER BY a.user_id
```

- add an index on login_time, if you use InnoDB to improve perfromance.
- try to reduce the selected date by setting a WHERE clause (e.g. only show active users [where u.status = 'active'])
- you can also limit the shown records by setting a limit at the end of the statement like LIMIT 10

Comment: The join with `aaa` is to select only logged-in users, it appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(a.login_time), '%Y-%m-%d')    
FROM aaa AS a,
JOIN user b
ON b.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY b.user_id ORDER BY b.user_id
```

or only dates by

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(a.login_time), '%Y-%m-%d')    
FROM aaa AS a
```

Then put an `INDEX` on `login_time` and both user_id's if you haven't done yet

```
CREATE INDEX idx_login_time ON aaa(login_time) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: I suspect `login_time` is in the `user` table, not `aaa`.

Comment: I'm not sure either...
_"table user contains all user id and other details,table aaa contains who and all logged into the application – user2527657"_

Comment: I read that, and I assume login time is one of the "other details"

Comment: login_time is in aaa table

Answer (score 0):

Give `user` a composite index on `user_id` and `login_time`:

```
alter table user add index (user_id, login_time);
```

This will be used to optimize the join with `aaa` and to find the maximum login time for each user.

To take full advantage of this index, it might be necessary to get the maxes in a subquery:

```
select date_format(max_login, '%Y-%m-%d')
from aaa as b
join (select user_id, max(login_time) max_login
      from user
      group by user_id) a
on a.user_id = b.user_id
order by b.user_id
```

Comment: This could actually be slower -- he only cares about users from the aaa table and if aaa is significantly smaller than user table this will be slower.

Comment: @Hogan True, it depends on the data. EXPLAIN can help determine which is better.